# Alfresco share ClientAbortException

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Sometimes when we open folder, Alfresco shows spinning wheel and never opens the folder. The log has below exception.

```
        2016-03-08 11:45:40,652  INFO  [webscripts.connector.RemoteClient] [http-bio-8080-exec-494] Exception calling (GET) http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/slingshot/doclib/treenode/site/test/documentLibrary/Books/science?children=true&max=-1&alf_ticket=TICKET_400a73c20348346eed011695af270f837f27a654
 2016-03-08 11:45:40,652  INFO  [webscripts.connector.RemoteClient] [http-bio-8080-exec-494] Error status 500 null
 ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:413)
```

If I curl the above URL or open directly in webrowser I am able to get the json response successfully.

I am using only Alfresco Share and not anyother client. The localhost:8080 is working perfectly fine in most of the cases except this one.

Can anyone please tell me what is the issue and why connection is closed or ClientAbortException exception is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly this is an issue of timeout and you'll need active monitoring on your Alfresco & Share environment to see how Alfresco is running.

Easy check is to install some java monitoring or use Jmeter to load test the system and see how it responds on different load.

Mostly the outcome is more CPU/RAM for Alfresco :).

Comment: I am seeing one timeout tag in share-config-custom.xml. The default value is set to 7000. Is this value is too low. Changing this value will help me? I tried to set this value to 21000. Looks like it is working. But since the original issue is random i could not assure that this number is fixing the issue or not

Comment: Yes but like I said, you'll def need some monitoring to see how Alfresco performs during that time

Answer (score 0):

As Tahir Malik mentioned above, the issue is related to performance.

The ClientAbort error itself occurs when the client (in this case, Share) times out or the user cancels a download. The message on the log is type INFO. More details here: https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-20349

If you are on SSO and using Alfresco Enterprise 5.2.3 or 5.2.4, there is a chance that you may hit a similar bug, which is discussed in the [Alfresco Forum](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/240491-some-alfresco-share-proxy-requests-fail-with-500-http-status-code-although-alfresco-repository-returns-successfull-http-response-200). However, this particular bug would not show the **ClientAbortException**.